# Attribute rule works in Pro 2.9.2, but not in Pro 2.6.8

Tags: arcgis-pro, geometry, vertices, arcade, attribute-rules

I have a calculation attribute rule that works in Pro 2.9.2 (in a 2.9.2 FGDB). It updates the M-values of the polyline’s geometry:

```
function pythagoras(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
}

var geom = Dictionary(Text(Geometry($feature)));
var paths = geom['paths'];
var oldX = paths[0][0][0];
var oldY = paths[0][0][1];
var line_length = 0;

for (var path_idx in paths) {
    for (var point_idx in paths[path_idx]) {
        var newX = paths[path_idx][point_idx][0];
        var newY = paths[path_idx][point_idx][1];
        if (point_idx != 0) {
            line_length += pythagoras(oldX, oldY, newX, newY);
        }
        paths[path_idx][point_idx][-1] = line_length;
        oldX = newX;
        oldY = newY;
    }
}
return Polyline(geom);
```

However, if I create that attribute rule in Pro 2.6.8 (in a separate 2.6.8 FGDB), it doesn't work as expected. It runs without errors, and it even densifies true curves (which tells me that the code ***is*** running), but it doesn't update the M-values of the vertices properly (it sets the M-values to Nan).

Is there something in that script that is not supported in older versions of Arcade?

I believe the Dictionary(), Text(), and Geometry() functions are working ok (since the script successfully returns a densified geometry). So I think it must be something else.

Unfortunately, I can't upgrade Pro right now, since our version of license manager doesn't support later versions of Pro.

Comment: Just to be crystal clear when you say "I create that attribute rule in Pro 2.6.2 (FGDB)" are you saying you are using a geodatabase created in 2.6.2 but you are using 2.9 to create the rule or are you creating a rule in a geodatabase using ArcPro 2.6.2? I suspect no one will answer this question because who keeps multiple versions unless they are using some sort of virtual machine? I know I don't! Sorry!

Comment: @Hornbydd Good question. I have Pro 2.9.2 on a dev computer, where I dream of using the latest software (includes a 2.9.2 FGDB). And I have Pro 2.6.8 on a separate prod computer, with a separate 2.6.8 FGDB, using a version of license manager that can’t easily be updated (until IT does an upgrade project). I perform separate tests, with separate data, in each environment.

Comment: @Hornbydd : If there’s anyone out there who has Pro 2.6, or remembers the limitations in Arcade at that version, then they might be able to help me. But I agree, most people are lucky enough to have newer versions.

Comment: This should help:  https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/version-matrix/ - you can click into each version and see what was added.

Answer (score 2):

The following test script works in Pro 2.6.8. It adjusts the Y-coordinates, instead of the M-coordinates.

```
var geom = Dictionary(Text(Geometry($feature)));
var paths = geom['paths'];

for (var path_idx in paths) {
    for (var point_idx in paths[path_idx]) {
        paths[path_idx][point_idx][1] += 10
    }
}
return Polyline(geom);
```

[image]

---

However, if I change the script so that it updates the M-coordinates, instead of the Y-coordinates, then it **doesn't work.** I don't get any errors, but the M-values just get updated to `Nan`, which isn't what I want.

```
var geom = Dictionary(Text(Geometry($feature)));
var paths = geom['paths'];

for (var path_idx in paths) {
    for (var point_idx in paths[path_idx]) {
        paths[path_idx][point_idx][2] += 10
    }
}
return Polyline(geom);
```

[image]

That tells me that there is a **bug in Pro 2.6.8.** It isn't able to update the geometry's M-values correctly.

(And for what it's worth, I tried using the `Geometry()` function, instead of the `Polyline()` function, to return the value to the geometry. Similarly, that worked for Y-coordinates, but not M-coordinates).

---

I don't have that problem in Pro 2.9.2. The script can update M-values without issue:

[image]

So I think the problem only exists in older versions like 2.6.8.